# cant get the correct value while using GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage() Unreal engine 2.27

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am trying to add a lean function to my c++ project, after calculating the YawDelta I want to displayed to my screen using the `GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage()`

the problem it's always 0 in the viewport screen when pressing play
[image]

here is my c++ code of the Lean function which is called in UpdateAnimationProperties (Tick)

```
void UShooterAnimInstance::Lean(float DeltaTime)
{
    if (ShooterCharacter == nullptr) return;
    CharacterYawLastFrame = CharacterYaw;
    CharacterYaw = ShooterCharacter->GetActorRotation().Yaw;

    const float Target{ (CharacterYaw - CharacterYawLastFrame) / DeltaTime };
    
    const float Interp{ FMath::FInterpTo(YawDelta, Target, DeltaTime, 6.f) };
    YawDelta = FMath::Clamp(Interp, -90.f, 90.f);

    if (GEngine) GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(5,
        -1,
        FColor::Cyan,
        FString::Printf(TEXT("YawDelta : %f"),
            YawDelta));
    
}
```

PS: if I use UE_LOG, the output log shows the variable 2 times, one with the correct value and the other one is always 0

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling the `AddOnScreenDebugMessage` with YawDelta in the AnimInstance's `NativeUpdateAnimation` ? Try it there after `Super::NativeUpdateAnimation(DeltaSeconds)`and see what result you get.